# Insert value of 10 in MySQL Double(9,8) column and end up with 9.99999999

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has a Double(9,8) column. When I try to insert a value of 10 from PHP in that column I end up with 9.99999999.

I can understand rounding errors but this is a whole number in the first place. Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Are you aware that `10` does not fit into your data type? Were you expecting an error message instead?

Comment: Are you sure you want DOUBLE instead of DECIMAL?... and see comments below

Comment: It should have generated an error.. as the answer below says. may be you should check your MY SQL version..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Double(9,8)` means:

- **9** digits overall
- of which **8** digits are decimals

This is the format a number will look like:

```
0.00000000
```

So the closest you can get by inputting **10** is **9.9999999**

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html):

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: **FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D)**. Here, “(M,D)”means than values can be stored with up to **M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point**. For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is 999.0001.

Comment: Upvote! Why won't it generate error?? What would it do when we insert 15 or any bigger number?

Comment: Now I get it. So if a value can go up to 336,000,000.00000000 then the data type should be Double(17,8)?

Comment: @Tauseef Strange thing is, it does print an error when I tried in SQLFiddle...  `Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'y' at row 1:`

Comment: @Bushstar yes, but I would recommend `DECIMAL(17,8)` instead for these, the floating point representations (REAL, DOUBLE, FLOAT...) are tricky, [the question of precision is not a straightforward one](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)...

Comment: well I would say its weird. may be he has very old version of MYSQL.

Comment: @Tauseef the oldest I could try on SQLFiddle is 5.1.61, and that reported the error too. I suspect some DB setting is set to allow this, but that would take a proper DBA to tell.

Comment: Thanks ppeterka 66, I will make your recommended change.

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical example of the *data loss as a feature* approach used by MySQL. You can avoid it if you harden the SQL mode (something I absolutely recommend):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo (
    ->  bar DOUBLE(9,8)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
```

Legacy mode features data loss:

```
mysql> SET sql_mode='';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (10);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.06 sec)

mysql> SELECT bar FROM foo;
+------------+
| bar        |
+------------+
| 9.99999999 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Strict modes do not:

```
mysql> SET sql_mode='TRADITIONAL';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (10);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'bar' at row 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D) - Here, “(M,D)” means than values can be stored with up to M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point. For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999 when displayed

You will need to add a higher value to `M`

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-float.html

USe decimal if you need precision

also, double(9, 8) means maximum value is 9,99999999

Answer (score 0):

Every number after the comma is the amount you entered after the comma. A weird sentence but certainely a correct one.

This is how i set keys in a DB.